# Trying to pass object assigned checkedValue using jquery map, returning null?

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I have been puzzling over this for the past three days and have gotten to a point where I really don't know what else to do. I'll explain the situation:

I have a for-each set up to display an observable array that was populated from an ajax GET request to a Sharepoint library. It is set up to display inside of a table and inside of this table I am adding checkboxes to each row with a checkedValue assignment of $data to pull in the objects selected. The thing that is puzzling me, is I can pass down a specific value of a property on the object and it will be the correct value, but if I try to pass down the whole object and then step into the object using dot(.Id) notation, the value I know exists console logs as undefined. My first instinct is that it is a quirk of $data in knockout that I am just unfamiliar with, but this is the first project I am having to use it on. Usually prefer Angular myself, but work wants otherwise, oh well.

Code is snipped below:

HTML:

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach: budgetDocs">
<tr>
    <!--<td style="width: 5%" class="glyphicon     glyphicon-triangle-right"></td>-->
    <!--checkedValue: Id, click: $root.selectedDoc,-->
    <!--Code above is to be pasted back into checkbox input upon finishing practice with checkboxes in knockout--> 
    <td style="width: 5%;"><input type="checkbox" class="budgets" data-bind="checked:$root.koselectedDocs, checkedValue:$data" /></td>
    <td style="width: 5%;"><img src="/_catalogs/masterpage/scripts/css/Excel-icon.png" width="25px"/></td>
    <td style="width: 35%;"><a class="docA" data-bind="text: Title, click: $root.openDoc"></a></td>
    <td style="width: 25%;" data-bind="text: Property.PropertyID"></td>
    <td style="width: 15%;" data-bind="text: Status"></td>
    <!--Failed Attempt at new doc button placement-->
    <!--<td style="width: 15%;"><button type="button">New Doc</button></td>-->
</tr>
</tbody>
```

Javascript:

```
self.postStatusUpdate = function(){         
    var selectedDocs = $("input:checkbox:checked").map(function ()
    {
        return $(this).val();
    }).get();

    for (var i = 0; i < selectedDocs.length; i++) {
        var item = selectedDocs[i];
        if(item.Id){
            console.dir(item.Id);
        }
        else{console.log('No dice')}
        }
    return true;
}
```

Thank you for whatever insight you may be able to provide me into why this happens.

Comment: Can you provide a jsffidle example of your code with hard coded data ?

Comment: Are you parsing it somewhere? What you're showing would seem to be an array of `string` since you're returning the `$(this).val()` in `.map()`. Or is `.val()` overridden to provide something different?

Comment: @squint I may actually be unaware of how .val() really functions. I was under the impression that using .val would return the value of the input a la <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checkedValue:$data">
Whatever checkedValue equals would be passed down regardless of what type value it is, object, string or otherwise.

Comment: That's where I'm not sure if the framework you use alters the behavior of `.val()`. In standard jQuery, it would just return a string. What do you get with `console.log(typeof item)` in the loop?

Comment: @squint I receive string in my console log, which really shouldn't happen since what I am passing it is an object. Is this a quirk of .val or .map? I am using vanilla jquery paired up with knockout.js for my view on a .aspx file.

Comment: @ZacharyMixon: Element attribute values are generally strings, except in a couple cases where they may be a number or boolean. So if the object is coming from the server, it must be in some format to be parsed. If you're trying to assign an object in JS to a `value` attribute, it will be converted to a string, which likely will result in `"[object Object]"`. I just don't know anything about the Knockout, so I'm not sure how that factors in.

Comment: @squint that is exactly what is happening: "[object Object]" whenever I console.dir the whole object. Is there any way to actually have it pass down the whole object so I can use it in my POST function or will I need to only pass down specific values in the object and try to work with what is possible?

Comment: Generally speaking, you can convert your object to JSON data for the purpose of data transmission. This should only really be needed if you're setting the object on the server to deliver it to the client. If your server-side language is JavaScript, then it's as simple as `JSON.stringify(my_object)` when you assign it as the value of the attribute. If some other language, you'll need to check their docs.

Comment: @squint I appreciate the help you've provided! I believe the object is actually a JSON response that we receive from Sharepoint, so I will look into deserializing it for use. Thanks :)

Comment: You're welcome. And if you're already getting JSON data, and just need to pass it on, you should be able to do so in its original form. It could be that the software is parsing it automatically into JS objects, which would explain why you're getting `[object Object]`. Good luck!